# Is it possible to embed an iframe within a B2C custom website?

Tags: html, iframe, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to have an iframe besites my main login to show some advertising for my company (like Salesforce here: https://login.salesforce.com/). Now my html looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- Here is my whole b2c-content -->
    <div id="b2c-content">...</div>

    <!-- This is the iframe with the ad -->
    <iframe src="url" title="iFrame title"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

My css and everything is working fine while testing, but when i upload it to my blob-storage in b2c and want to test it on the website, the iFrame is not shown. Also when I inspect the webpage, there is no iframe in the html-content. In the inspector it is looking like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- Here is my whole b2c-content -->
    <div id="b2c-content">...</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a good solution for this?

I also tried putting the iframe in a separate container but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I had to add the following lines within the `RelyingParty` in my Custom Policy:

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignIn" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <!-- Added this: Enabling JavaScript -->
    <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
</RelyingParty>
```